# When I use react-datepicker , Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

The UI appears, but the e.target.value cannot be read.
Clicking on a calendar will result in an error.

There are two errors.I'll show you two errors through the picture first.

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/culZK.png)
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3YJ8.png)

So, this is my code. The main component refers to this component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const DatePick = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState("");

  const startDateHandler = (event) => {
    const gettodate = setStartDate(event.target.value);
    console.log(gettodate);
  };
  return (
    <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={startDateHandler} dateFormat={"yyyyMMdd"} showYearDropdown scrollableMonthYearDropdown />
  );
};

export default DatePick;
```

If I use

`(date)=>setStartdate(date)`

instead of handler, the value is undefined. how can i solve this problem ? i wanna get value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can handle DatePicker value as (date)=>setStartdate(date).

Comment: but, the value is undefined. i wanna get data like 20220317

Comment: value is not needed in DatePicker handle change

 <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartdate(date)}
      />

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).